# How do I connect two trees with qtree?

Tags: tikz-trees, qtree

I would like to take the following code that I created and do something along the lines in http://alpage.inria.fr/~clerger/tutorial/tag_example.png for the middle two trees where dotted lines are connecting the Vs to the V in the left tree. Is that possible (I prefer tikz)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}


\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{ll}

\Tree [.S [.NP John ] [.VP [.V sleeps ] ] ]

&

\Tree [.V [.V ] [.Adv a lot ] ]

\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

It would also be nice not to split "a lot" into two nodes as in my tree and not in the example I sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is using `tikz-qtree` an option? Then you can place both trees in the same `tikzpicture`, using a `scope` to `xshift` the second one, adding named nodes to the tree where needed, and drawing arrows between those nodes.

For the last question: `{a lot}`, not `a lot`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\Tree [.\node (s) {S}; [.NP John ] [.VP [.\node(v1){V}; sleeps ] ] ]

\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\Tree [.\node(v2){V}; [.\node(v3){V}; ] [.Adv {a lot} ] ]
\end{scope}

\path (s) -- node[yshift=4pt] {$\stackrel{\text{adj}}{\implies}$} (v2);

\draw [red,dashed,-stealth] (v2) to[bend right] (v1);
\draw [red,dashed,-stealth] (v3) to[bend right] (v1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: May I also ask how you would go on about drawing the double arrows in between trees? If I just see an example here for the above two trees (though there are no double arrows between them in the original example), I think I will be able to generalize.

Comment: @user2299502 You mean the ones with *subst* and *adj* at the top of the diagram? You could do something like `\node at (1.5,0) {$\stackrel{adj}{\implies}$};` (requires `\usepackage{amsmath}`).

Comment: (Added vanilla qtree version of this answer.)

Comment: @alexis "You can also place two trees made with regular `qtree` in the same `tikzpicture`" -- only if the entire trees are placed inside nodes, and then you have nest a tikzpicture inside it again to get named nodes (bad practice).  And it isn't what you did in your answer either. You placed three separate `tikzpicture`s inside `qtree` trees, and used a fourth `tikzpicture` to draw the lines. By the way, if TikZ is used elsewhere in the OPs document, `\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture] ` could cause problems, so I'd probably avoid it.

Comment: You're right, I discovered the same when I tried it out-- that's why I ended up writing a separate answer. Neglected to correct the original comment; deleted now.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use `tikz-qtree` for this: Although regular `qtree` doesn't use `tikz` internally, it is fully compatible with it. Here is Torbjørn's tikz solution translated to use regular `qtree` (and using the OP's method for placing trees side by side):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{qtree}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture] 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\Tree [.S [.NP John ] [.VP [.\tikz\node(v1){V}; sleeps ] ] ]
&
\Tree [.\tikz\node(v2){V}; [.\tikz\node(v3){V}; ] [.Adv {a lot} ] ]
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\draw [red,dashed,-stealth] (v2) to[bend right] (v1);
\draw [red,dashed,-stealth] (v3) to[bend right] (v1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]